# Когда обособляются "да" и "нет"?

Tags: запятые

Ставится ли запятая в предложении: "Вроде бы нет" или это выражение тесно связано между собой по смыслу?

Comment: "Выражение тесно связано между собой" =>  Как понять такое: "Оно связано между собой"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не ставится.

> [ВРОДЕ (БЫ)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_806), частица
> Не требует постановки знаков препинания.
> Правда, на улице Леплевский держался несколько поодаль от Ивана, его решимости вроде поубавилось. В. Быков, Народные мстители. «Мы не заблудимся? – озабоченно спросил он. – Ведь вроде уже должен быть пляж». В. Пелевин, Жизнь насекомых. Произошло это вроде бы перед самой войной, не то в конце мая, не то в начале июня 1941 года... В. Войнович, Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина.

"Вроде бы нет". Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> ― Не звонила она? ― **Вроде бы нет**. Мне ни к чему. [И. Грекова. Летом в городе (1962)]
>
> Разве в 2001-м кто-нибудь поднимал панику? ― **Вроде бы нет**. Но это не значит, что все было хорошо. [Анастасия Нарышкина. Неоправданный страх безработицы. Рынок труда (2003) // «Известия», 2003.02.18]
>
> ― Работать не разучился? ― **Вроде бы нет**. ― Хочешь опять попробовать? [Геннадий Прашкевич, Александр Богдан. Человек «Ч» (2001)]
>
> ― спросил Виноградов. ― **Вроде бы нет**. А там, кто знает… [Петр Галицкий. Опасная коллекция (2000)]
>
> ― Лариса, ты ничего тревожного не замечала? ― **Вроде бы нет**. Правда, вчера какой-то плюгавый в универсаме рядом со мной болтался, пытался даже прижаться вроде бы случайно. [Лев Корнешов. Газета (2000)]
>
> Может быть, была получена какая-то другая, тайная существенная информация? **Вроде бы нет**. Положительные эмоции и престиж США ― это, в основном, актив. [Константин Феоктистов. Траектория жизни (2000)]
>
> ― А не трусишь? ― **Вроде бы нет**. ― Почему вроде бы? [Юрий Сенкевич. Путешествие длиною в жизнь (1999)]
>
> ― Тристан и Изольда? ― **Вроде бы нет**. ― Антоний и Клеопатра? [Василий Катанян. Прикосновение к идолам (1998)]
>
> ― **Вроде бы нет**, у нас на курсе такого не было. [Татьяна Рассказова, Лариса Лужина. От вечной невесты до царицы // «Общая газета», 1998]
>
> Есть у них в доме осина? **Вроде бы нет**. А как она вообще выглядит, осина? [Сергей Лукьяненко. Ночной дозор (1998)]
>
> **Да вроде бы нет**, просят о возвышенном, о благородном. [Валерий Попов. Будни гарема (1994)]
>
> Санька ответил не сразу, прислушался: ― **Да вроде бы нет**. Хотя постой! [Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон (1968-1991)]

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не ставится – нет причин для постановки. Вводными словами "вроде" и "вроде бы" не являются.